# Can't understand Mean Absolute Error (MAE) formulation

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, machine-learning

I'm reading `Taylor Cross Entropy Loss` [paper](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/2020/0305.pdf) and came across the formulation of Mean Absolute Error (MAE), which is described as following:

$$
\mathcal{L}_{MAE}(f({\bf x}), y) = \Vert{e_y - f({\bf x})}\Vert_{1} = 2 - 2f_y({\bf x})
$$

As mentioned in the linked paper's section **3.1**, $e_y$ is one hot encoded vector having same dimension as $f({\bf x})$.

What I don't understand is that from where does the constant `2` come from in above formulation? I'm referring to this formulation if `MAE` on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error).

Any hint/reference would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit**

As requested in the comment, here is the context of the above formulation.

- The linked paper talks about training a deep neural network for `k` class classification. ${\bf x}$ is a feature vector (e.g. image of cat) and $y$ is ground truth label.
- The neural network is represented as an unknown complex function $f$.
- $e_y$ is one hot encoded vectors of ground truths. For example, if `k=2` (cat and dog), then $e_y = [0, 1]$ for cat and $e_y = [1, 0]$ for dog.
- $f({\bf x})$ is what predicted by neural network. It can be probabilities for each class. For example, a well trained neural network will output $f({\bf x}) = [0.05, 0.95]$ for an image of cat.
- The mean absolute difference between ground truth labels and the predicted outputs for all images is what I refer to `MAE`.

Comment: You should provide more context in your question (what is $f_y$, what are the elements of $e_y$, what is the range of $f$, etc)

Comment: @LinAlg Sure! Updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose both $e_y$ and $f(x)$ are vectors where a single element has value $1$ and all other elements have value $0$. Therefore, $\Vert{e_y - f({\bf x})}\Vert_{1}=0$ if the position of the $1$ is the same in both vectors, and $\Vert{e_y - f({\bf x})}\Vert_{1}=2$ if the position is not the same. For $e_y$, the $1$ is at position $y$, so if $(f({\bf x}))_y$ is also $1$, the error is $0$.

Interestingly, the formula also holds  when the assumption on $f(x)$ is relaxed to assuming that the elements are nonnegative and sum to $1$:
\begin{align}\Vert{e_y - f({\bf x})}\Vert_{1} &= \sum_j |(e_y)_j - (f(x))_j| \\
&= |(e_y)_y - (f(x))_y| + \sum_{j:j\neq y} |(e_y)_j - (f(x))_j| \\
&= |1 - (f(x))_y| + \sum_{j:j\neq y} |0 - (f(x))_j| \\
&= 1 - (f(x))_y + \sum_{j:j\neq y} (f(x))_j \\
&= 1 - 2(f(x))_y + \sum_j (f(x))_j \\
&= 2 - 2(f(x))_y
\end{align}

Comment: I've updated the question. What you mentioned is true in an ideal case. The max error can be 2 and the min error can be 0. But in actual case, $f$ will have probabilities and not exact `1` and `0`. Even in ideal case, I'm not sure how is this written: $\Vert{e_y - f({\bf x})}\Vert_{1} = 2 - 2f_y({\bf x})$.

Comment: @Kaushal28 I have updated the answer

Comment: Wow, you really generalized it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LinAlg, I got the answer. I'm writing it for 2 classes and can be generalized further.

Consider the predictions $ f({\bf x}) = [\epsilon, 1-\epsilon]$ and ground truths $e_y = [1, 0]$. The mean absolute error will be

$$MAE = |1-\epsilon| + |-1+\epsilon| = 2 - 2\epsilon$$

This will be same even if $e_y = [0, 1]$.